# I want to launch a new activity on clicking a card view in a fragment please help me with this code

Tags: java, android, android-intent, fragment, android-cardview

I am new android programming. I have created a card view in the a fragment. Here i am trying to go to a new activity on clicking the cardview.

**ON CLICK FUNCTION**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_samples, container, false);
    CardView bro,invi,cert,ban,card;
    cert=(CardView)RootView.findViewById(R.id.certid);
    cert.setOnClickListener(this);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_samples, container, false);
}

  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i ;
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.certid :
        i=new Intent(view.getContext(),certificates.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `return RootView;` in `onCreateView()`. As you have it now, you're returning a different inflated `View` that you've not done any setup on.

Comment: Yeah... This cleared my doubt.